# Reactjs İmage sources seeming like src="[object Module]"

Tags: html, reactjs, image, webpack

In Reactjs image sources seeming like src="[object Module]". But somehow .svg files not have this issue and it only occurs and some .png files even with the static ones. For example:

```
<div className="flex-row stores-main">
                <a
                    href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx"
                    target="_blank"
                >
                    <img
                        alt="play-store"
                        className="play-store"
                        src={require("../../assets/stores/google-play-badge.png")}
                    />
                </a>
                <a
                    href="https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/verified/xxx"
                    target="_blank"
                >
                    <img
                        alt="apple-store"
                        className="apple-store"
                        src={require("../../assets/stores/apple-store-badge.png")}
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
```

In here play-store image rendering normal but apple-store image is not rendering and i am sure that the paths are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how did you load this template with `webpack` inside a html plugin or a via a loader but looks like `require('thing')` returns a module object which has `default` prop as a string path you need.

```js
src={require("../../assets/stores/apple-store-badge.png").default}
```

I'm guessing you currently have enabled `esModule` object for a loader which is likely `file-loader` or `url-loader` causing the issue. If so, you just simply turn it off then it exports the right url for you (without exporting as a module)